# How to get file from Azure services(Azure blob storage) using Azure Service Principal Name(SPN) using C#.net?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-blob-storage, spn

In General, I want to get files from the Azure blob storage account using C#.net, and I have an SPN name.
I have tried the following ways to do it.

> Note: Here Authentication key stored in KEY Vault and Azure admin
> provide us only SPN Name

Way 1:

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
string accessToken = "";
            try
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{TenantID}");
                var credential = new ClientCredential("{ClientID}", "{SPN Name}");
                var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com", credential);

                if (result == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to authenticate via ADAL");
                }
                accessToken = result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Exception for get Blob container" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
```

Way 2:

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
 var serviceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(serviceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
          
            SecretBundle secretValue = null;
            try
            {
                secretValue = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("{KeyVault URI}", {SPN_Name});
            }
            catch (Exception kex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Exception for get Blob container" + kex.Message.ToString());
            }
           return secretValue.Value;
```

Following code to Access File from Azure Storage

```
public static async Task<List<IListBlobItem>> GetBlobContainer( string containerName)
        var token = await GetAccessToken();
                TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(token);
        //here i am getting all one day file
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                date = date.AddDays(-1);
               
                StorageCredentials _objectCrentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

                CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri($"{Storage Account URI}"), _objectCrentials);
                // container
                CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
                IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> listOfBlob = blobContainer.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlob>()
                   .OrderByDescending(b => b.Properties.LastModified > date);
                //check her do you get any list
                _list = listOfBlob.ToList();
```

> Way 2 have gives this error.
>
> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
> Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
> [https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}](https://login.windows.net/%7BtenantID%7D). Exception Message: Tried the
> following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
> Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
> [https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}](https://login.windows.net/%7BtenantID%7D). Exception Message: Tried to get
> token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the
> Instance Metadata Service (IMDS). Skipping request to the Managed
> Service Identity (MSI) token endpoint. Parameters: Connection String:
> [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net,
> Authority: [https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}](https://login.windows.net/%7BtenantID%7D). Exception Message:
> Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be
> acquired. Exception for Visual Studio token provider
> Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe : TS003: Error, TS005: No accounts
> found. Please go to Tools->Options->Azure Services Authentication, and
> add an account to be to authenticate to Azure services during
> development.
>
> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
> Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
> [https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}](https://login.windows.net/%7BtenantID%7D). Exception Message: Tried to get
> token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.

Please correct me if followed wrong steps.

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: For Way 1 not able to connect and 2 way give an error that added to the story.

Comment: Is that you store azure storage account key in Azure key vault?

Comment: Yes, store value in the azure key vault and gave the principal name .

Comment: If so,  I think you should update your code as `var key=await GetAccessToken() StorageCredentials _objectCrentials = new StorageCredentials(<accountName>,key);`

Comment: You can download connection string for your blob storage account by logging into Azure account and add in your web.config file like below:
`<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME;AccountKey=YOUR_ACCOUNT_KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />`

Comment: Actually, it raises an error at GetAccessToken, before getting a token.

Comment: @RajeevKumar, there is no direct access, It has created SPN to access Azure blob storage. And Storing Credentials into Web config is actually not good practice so Azure has a key vault.

Comment: @DeepakPatel Could you please tell me when you get error?  Getting key from the key vault or connecting azure blob?

Comment: @DeepakPatel Besides If you want to use sp to access Azure blob, you need to assign  `Storage Blob Data Contributor:` to the sp. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad

Comment: @JimXu thanks for the reference I will check, and have error on getting the key from the key vault.

Comment: @DeepakPatel Is that you run the application vai vs 2019? If so, according to the error and your code, you need to configure some things. First, add account in VS 2019 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-visual-studio. Second, you need to configure right access policy for the account in Azure key vault.

Comment: @JimXu our Team missed to give us Client Secret key, and we were trying without that.

Comment: @DeepakPatel Do you have any updates?

Comment: @JimXu They changed their flow of coding now we are using a direct connection string to access the Azure blob storage account.

Comment: Looks like this issue has been resolved right? Can you post an answer so that this issue can be treated as archived?

Comment: Unfortunately, Allen, We have to change our way to access files from the storage container.
We are using now the direct way instead of going to SPN name.